# How do I change parts of my terminal prompt?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

In Terminal it says

```
Last login: Mon Jan 13 00:00:14 on ttys000
Logsdon:~ DomGomez$
```

How do I change the DomGomez part in Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with customising your `.bashrc`, I would suggest customising your `prompt`(PS1). [Here is a tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) among (a lot of) others about it.

Answer (score -1):

first and foremost, that is not your host name as I believe.

`Logsdon` is your hostname, `DomGomez` is your username.

To change your hostname, `Logsdon` to something else, just go to `Sharing` under System Preferences, and you will find an edit button on the upper panel.

To change your username, here's a [official Apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428) detailing how.

Do backup before proceeding as the apple doc suggests.

I personally don't suggest doing that as I have failed before.